# How To Create an External reference page for Google Sheet On a Google Site

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sites

I Have created a `Google Sheet` Including some data of the students.[Example Data Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D4BQYqpwK6v3UYsZo7NCO_ew3crOJQBM7e2F2FLsU8Q/edit?usp=sharing)

Now I want to create a `google site` page ,So that my Students can `confirm` whether the data entered is correct (My Google sheet will include over 3000 Student data)

### CREATING A SEARCH PAGE

[image: Search Page Look 1] The Page will look like this and when the student start typing his/her unique Id this must give `predictive` Id's from the Id list in the `column A` in [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D4BQYqpwK6v3UYsZo7NCO_ew3crOJQBM7e2F2FLsU8Q/edit?usp=sharing)

in example when the student start typing `199` something like a dropdown will show filter the id's that starts with 199 that is in the  `column A` in [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D4BQYqpwK6v3UYsZo7NCO_ew3crOJQBM7e2F2FLsU8Q/edit?usp=sharing)

### CREATING A DETAIL PAGE

- After the Student type his/her Id and click on the search button the data entered under that ID should be shown vertically

As an example when a student search his ID `198980204105`, then it should search `column A` in [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D4BQYqpwK6v3UYsZo7NCO_ew3crOJQBM7e2F2FLsU8Q/edit?usp=sharing) for his id and accordingly give the other results as in the below picture

[image: SEARCH RESULTS FOR-198980204105]

In this example

- The student searched for his ID `198980204105`
- This id `198980204105` is located in the cell `A11` in the [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D4BQYqpwK6v3UYsZo7NCO_ew3crOJQBM7e2F2FLsU8Q/edit?usp=sharing)
- Because the ID is in row `11` the details in the row `11` is shown as in the above picture

### POINTS TO CONCERN

- I want this User interface to be added into a `google site` therefore it should be compatible with `google site`
- I have more than `3000` User Data and adding

Answer (score 0):

**How to create a web form to get data from Google Sheets**

This tutorial will show you how you can create a web form to search and get data from Google Sheets. You can share this web form with others and let them search for data in your Google Sheet.

This is also useful when you want to share a part of your Google Sheets without giving access to your entire Spreadsheet. In such cases, you can create user-friendly web pages to share your Google Sheets data using this method.

There are two methods that you can follow to work with Google Apps Script. The first is [Container-bound Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound), and the second is [Standalone Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone). Here I am using the second, so it does not bound the script to the Google Sheet.

**Live demo**

You can access the live web form and the Google Sheet used in this tutorial from the following links.

1. [LIVE FORM](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxaqvMc5S5vB8VVbbt4fAwEECS5qLCo94uMKd8HkX_l66JqQDY/exec)
2. [GOOGLE SHEET (DATA SOURCE)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/142FbylWc7109R0RsXQ42NuN_TFs-D3RTtIYJOSBR1QM/edit?usp=sharing)
3. [VIDEO DEMO](https://564898-1821151-raikfcquaxqncofqfm.stackpathdns.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/How-to-create-a-web-form-to-get-data-from-Google-Sheets-demo.mp4)

**How to create the above web form to get data from Google Sheets**

> Step 01 – Prepare your Google Sheet

For this tutorial, you can either use your own data sheet (A Google Sheet) or you can make a copy of the Google Sheet used in this tutorial from the following link. You can also use the [Spreadsheet ID](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id) of this Google Sheet, even without copying it to your Google Drive.
[LINK TO THE GOOGLE SHEET (DATA SOURCE)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/142FbylWc7109R0RsXQ42NuN_TFs-D3RTtIYJOSBR1QM/edit?usp=sharing)

> Step 02 – Make a copy of the Google Apps Script file

You can make a copy of the Google Apps Script file to your drive from the following link.

[LINK TO THE APP SCRIPT](https://script.google.com/home/projects/14PFA3tLhkZTSp5TRAFZfPdc4EAH-heYLICQ13xau7MbK3SejKSnwqGKi/edit)

The above Google Apps Script file contains the following two files. Here I am not going to explain the code line by line. Instead, I will briefly explain the purpose of each file and function below

1. Index.html
2. Code.gs

   ***1. Index.html file***
   This file includes the HTML code for the search form and required JavaScript files and functions. Here I am using Bootstrap for styling the form and table. You can see included Bootstrap related files in, line 5,6, and 7.

The search form is from lines 89 to 97. Once you hit the **search button**, it will execute the handleFormSubmit JavaScript function (in, line 24). This function gets the relevant **search results** from the server (explain below) and passes them to the createTable function (line 30).

In the createTable function, lines from 35 to 59 are the **column headers** of the result table. You should write this in the same order as in your Google Sheet. The dataArray variable contains the search results received from handleFormSubmit function. The createTable function creates the table from the values in the dataArray variable and print the results inside  in line 106.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         
        <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        <script>
          //PREVENT FORMS FROM SUBMITTING / PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR
          function preventFormSubmit() {
            var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
            for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
              forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              });
            }
          }
          window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmit, true); 
              
           
          //HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION
          function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
            document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
          }
         
          //CREATE THE DATA TABLE
          function createTable(dataArray) {
            if(dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0){
              var result = "<table class='table table-sm table-striped' id='dtable' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+
                           "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+
                             "<tr>"+                               //Change table headings to match witht he Google Sheet
                              "<th scope='col'>ORDERNUMBER</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>QUANTITYORDERED</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>PRICEEACH</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>ORDERLINENUMBER</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>SALES</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>ORDERDATE</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>STATUS</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>QTR_ID</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>MONTH_ID</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>YEAR_ID</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>PRODUCTLINE</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>MSRP</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>PRODUCTCODE</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>CUSTOMERNAME</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>PHONE</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>ADDRESSLINE1</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>ADDRESSLINE2</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>CITY</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>STATE</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>POSTALCODE</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>COUNTRY</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>TERRITORY</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>CONTACTLASTNAME</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>CONTACTFIRSTNAME</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>DEALSIZE</th>"+
                            "</tr>"+
                          "</thead>";
              for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
                  result += "<tr>";
                  for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
                      result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
                  }
                  result += "</tr>";
              }
              result += "</table>";
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              div.innerHTML = result;
            }else{
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              //div.empty()
              div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
            }
          }
        </script>
        <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ~ END ---------------------------------------------------- -->
         
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
             
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ------------------------------------------------ -->
                  <form id="search-form" class="form-inline" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                      <label for="searchtext">Search Text</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext" name="searchtext" placeholder="Search Text">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Search</button>
                  </form>
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ~ END ------------------------------------------- -->
               
              </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
             
                <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ------------------------------------------------ -->
                <div id="search-results" class="table-responsive">
                  <!-- The Data Table is inserted here by JavaScript -->
                </div>
                <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ~ END ------------------------------------------------ -->
                   
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

***2. Code.gs file***
This file contains the server-side script. The above mentioned function handleFormSubmit in the Index.html file passes the formObject to the processForm function in this Code.gs file.

If the formObject contain searchtext, it passes to the search function.

In the search function, replace the spreadhseetId and the dataRange as per your Google Sheet and data range.

The search function look for matching contents in the Google Sheet and returns an array of rows back to the processForm function. It returns the results back to the handleFormSubmit function in the Index.html file.

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}
 
 
/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){  
  var result = "";
  if(formObject.searchtext){//Execute if form passes search text
      result = search(formObject.searchtext);
  }
  return result;
}
 
//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS 
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId   = '142FbylWc7109R0RsXQ42NuN_TFs-D3RTtIYJOSBR1QM'; //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRage        = 'Data!A2:Y';                                    //** CHANGE !!!
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRage).values;
  var ar = [];
   
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}
```

Once you have done all the coding, you can get a URL to this web app by deploying it as a web app. To do that,

1. Go to Google Apps Script file
2. Then go to “**Publish**” and select “**Deploy as web app…**“
3. For “**Execute the app as**“; field select **your email**.
4. Under “**Who has access to the app**“: option select “**Anyone**“
5. Click “**Update**“
6. **Copy the URL** in the next window and paste in the browser to access the form.

> Wrapping Up

With Google Apps Script, you can build various types of web apps for free. When building those web apps you may need to build a search option to get data from Google Sheets to the web app.

This tutorial explained to you how to create a basic search form in your web app to retrieve data from Google Sheets.

THE INSTRUCTIONS WAS TAKEN FROM
https://www.bpwebs.com/
***ALL CREDITS TO bpwebs.com
***I found the answer from this website